# Excel TREND function using a non-contiguous range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trend

I have 3 columns with multiple rows of data:

```
Date, Actuals, and Forecast.
```

I introduced a 4th column, Trend, and want to use the TREND function in Excel using the latest 3 values from actuals. However, when I reach the Sep-2020 row, I run out of actual values to illustrate the trend, so I want to use the last 2 actuals (Jun and Jul) plus the previous Forecast (Aug).

[image: This is what the file looks like]

Question: is there a way for the TREND function to consume non-contiguous cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D5 put:

```
=TREND(IF(B2:B4<>"",B2:B4,C2:C4),A2:A4,A5)
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version may necessitate the confirmation of the array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: this worked perfectly. I wasn't aware of this functionality and tried all sorts of workarounds instead. Thanks!

Comment: @user3191299 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.